# Create a select option with current quarter and previous 11 quarters

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I need to create a select box with options showing the current quarter and previous 11 quarters in my Vf page.

I dont want to hardcode them as the values would change with a new quarter. This should always default to current quarter.

Any pointers would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: :Im in a Similar requirement.i have a "Quarter" and Year as the field where it should get identified by product name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [apex:selectList](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm) with selectOptions to display:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!quarter}" multiselect="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!listOfQuarters}"/>
</apex:selectList><p/>
```

The controller could look like the following:

```
public List<SelectOption> getListOfQuarters() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    // non-dynamic code as an example

    options.add(new SelectOption('Q2 2012','Q2 2012'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q1 2012','Q1 2012'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q4 2011','Q4 2011'));

    return options;
}
```

To automatically generate the option values, I would use Datetime methods: *now()* to grab the current date, *month()* and *year()* to extract the month and year, and maybe use a Map to lookup the quarter by month, or divide the month number by three and use *ceil()* to get the current quarter.

To create the previous 11 quarters, use *addMonths()* with a negative value, three months at a time inside a loop.

```
myDatetime.addMonths(-3)
```

If you are not using calendar quarters you may be able to use SOQL to query the Period object.  You can definitely determine your fiscal year start month:

```
SELECT FiscalYearStartMonth FROM Organization
```